# Creating Combinations using CF List Loops

Tags: coldfusion, nested-loops

I'm working on a Coldfusion project and I seem to be stuck. I am a newbie so I hope I don't get too much slack. The purpose of my project is to create a password list by using nested loops. I am to design a template that combines all words in the list "cold, fusion, dynamic" with all words on the list "bert, ernie, oscar" to produce a bulleted list of vaild passwords. This template should process two URL prarameters named List1 and List2. I must use two list loops nested within each other to produce all possible combinations of words. (For example "coldbert", "coldernie", "coldoscar", "fusionbert" and so on..)

This is what I have so far:

```
<cfinclude template="header.cfm">
<body>

<h2>Loop List</h2>


<cfhttp url="looplist.cfm?List1=cold,fusion,dynamic&List2=bert,ernie,oscar" method="get">

<CFLOOP LIST="#URL.List1#"
INDEX="List1">
<UL><CFOUTPUT>#List1#</CFOUTPUT></UL><br>
</CFLOOP>


<cfinclude template="footer.cfm">
```

I want to ensure that I'm going in the right direction here. Thanks guys for any assistance.

Comment: I would start with figuring out the loop code first. Then figure out how to use it as a template. However, one issue with the above is the `URL.list1` variable will only exist on the page you are calling, ie `loopList.cfm`.

Comment: ... also, to avoid confusion do not use `List1` for both the index and variable names. Use two different names.

Answer (score 3):

Unless you're calling a page that doesn't exist on your site, I do not see a need to do a http call. You could just create a function in the template (although I'd prefer it to be in a separate cfc) and call that to get your password combos. Something like ...

```
<cffunction name="getPasswordCombos" returntype="string">
    <cfargument name="list1" type="string" required="true" />
    <cfargument name="list2" type="string" required="true" />

    <cfset var passwordCombos = "" />
    <cfset var i = "" />
    <cfset var j = "" />

    <!--- your combo generation logic might look something like --->
    <cfloop list="#arguments.list1#" index="i">
        <cfloop list="#arguments.list2#" index="j">
            .....
            <!--- set passwordCombos logic here --->
            .....
        </cfloop>           
    </cfloop>

    <cfreturn passwordCombos />
</cffunction>
```

Then,

```
<cfset passwordCombos = getPasswordCombos("cold,fusion,dynamic", "bert,ernie,oscar") />
```

Then loop over the "passwordCombos"

```
<ul>
    <cfloop list="#passwordCombos#" index="i">
        <li>#i#</li>
    </cfloop>
</ul>
```

Also, if you HAVE to user CFHTTP, use cfhttpparam to pass in arguments. It's much cleaner.

```
<cfhttp result="result" url="looplist.cfm" method="GET">
    <cfhttpparam name="list1" type="url" value="cold,fusion,dynamic">
    <cfhttpparam name="list2" type="url" value="bert,ernie,oscar">
</cfhttp>
```

Comment: Agreed. Unless the homework assignment *requires* using `cfhttp`, don't. There are simpler options.